# Can std::swap swap two structs in an array

Tags: c++

I have an array of structs

```
struct ItemType
{
    value_type data;
    size_type priority;
};
```

Can `std::swap` be used to swap the structs in the array so that I could do

```
std::swap(array[i], array[i+1]);
```

and come out with the intended result?

Comment: such questions often are motivated by code that does not work as intended, in that case you better show your code and the error message. Otherwise, what is preventing you from try it out and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, in general that can be done. But it depends on the structs (and your question does not show a [mcve], for example you do not say what `value_type` is). BTW, did you simply try it? What was the result?

Comment: it depends on `value_type` and `size_type`. Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it comes out with intended result. You can test the below code to see that it works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
  int x;
  string y;
};

int main() {
  A a1;
  a1.x = 5;
  a1.y = "hi";
  A a2;
  a2.x = 7;
  a2.y = "bye";
  A arr[2];
  arr[0] = a1;
  arr[1] = a2;
  swap(arr[0], arr[1]);
  cout << arr[0].x << " " << arr[1].y << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you swap a `int` and a `string`, but does it also work for a `value_type` and a`size_type`? Your code does not verify that. The question needs clarification

Answer (score 2):

You don't tell us anything about the types you want to swap.

From [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) we can read, that the data types which should be swapped, must be fullfill the following requirements:

> Type requirements
>
> T must meet the requirements of [MoveConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveConstructible) and [MoveAssignable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveAssignable).

```
struct A 
{   
    double x;
    std::vector<std::string> y;  
    void Print() const 
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
        for ( auto& el: y ) { std::cout << el << " "; }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

};  

int main() {
    A arr[]={{1.234,{"This","is","a","test"}},{ 5.678, {"which","is","simple"}}};
    arr[0].Print();
    arr[1].Print();

    std::swap(arr[0], arr[1]);
    arr[0].Print();
    arr[1].Print();
    return 0;
}
```

As long your types fulfill the requirements, it doesn't matter, that both are located in an array or not.

If your types are currently not fulfilling the requirements, it is typically possible to make them swappable by adding appropriated constructors to the struct.